# ActivityView and launching activities on secondary display

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to display (as a system-level application) multiple activities. There's an hidden AOSP class called [`ActivityView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityView.java) meant to do just that. Here's how you would use it, as far as I understand:

```
findViewById(R.id.view1).setCallback(object: ActivityView.StateCallback() {
    override fun onActivityViewReady(view: ActivityView?) {
        view?.startActivity(InnerActivity.getIntent(view.context, "my extra"))
    }

    override fun onActivityViewDestroyed(view: ActivityView?) {
        // Cleanup
    }
})
```

Note that the inner activity has to be declared with the attribute `allowEmbedded` set to true. It is in my case. My application also has the permission `android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS` (and is built as a system application, with the ROM certificate and installed in `/system/priv-app`)

Now, for the problem: when I call `startActivity`, the inner activity is displayed as a new activity on the stack, like any standard `Context.startActivity` call would do (the `ActivityView.startActivity` method actually does exactly that, but adds some options to the bundle before that, to display the activity on a virtual display). I also have a system Toast displayed that tells me that my `App does not support launch on secondary displays`.

In regard to this Toast, I tried giving my application the `android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT` permission, to no help.

I'm probably missing something related to the virtual display, but I can't see what…

(I know `ActivityView` is hidden, and that actually could be a bug, I'm just being curious of what it can or cannot do.)

Comment: did you ever come up with a good solution for this?

Comment: Sadly I did not. We didn't pursue that project for long...

Comment: bummer dude. I'm trying to solve this right now, we have a rooted emulator and all but the problem persists. seems like this feature is made specifically for this purpose, yet is non-functional

Answer (score 4):

I have already used ActivityView successfully on Android 9 (Pie). I noted some key points that you can refer to use ActivityView.

1. The application which use ActivityView need to be private application (installed in /system/priv-app) and must use system uid (declare in AndroidManifest.xml) as below

   > ```
   > <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     package="your.packagename"
   >     android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
   > ```
   >
   > Noted that you need to replace "your.packagename" by package name of your application
2. You need config Android framework to support secondary display by copy file android.software.activities_on_secondary_displays.xml to /system/etc/permissions/

   - Content of android.software.activities_on_secondary_displays.xml

     > ```
     > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     > <permissions>
     >     <feature name="android.software.activities_on_secondary_displays" />
     > </permissions>
     > ```
   - You should config in makefile to copy this file in building process of Android image from source code using PRODUCT_COPY_FILES
3. Enable resizeable mode and using singleTask for the Activity need to be placed inside an ActivityView

   In AndroidManifest.xml

   > ```
   > <activity
   >     android:name=".YourActivity"
   >     android:resizeableActivity="true"
   >     android:launchMode="singleTask">
   > ```

Comment: This is super helpful, but unfortunately, I'm still in the same issue as the original post. I have done the following: added necessary permissions in the Manifest (inject_events, etc) as per this article (https://medium.com/@dawidlijewski/activityview-advanced-way-of-composing-apps-6ca967e246ff), signed the application with the AOSP signature, added the activities_on_secondary_displays.xml via adb shell, and enabled resizeableActivity and allowEmbedded for the activity. Is there anything else that I might have missed?

Comment: @SumukhAnand were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must add these two attributes to the Activity tag in your manifest for any activity which should be allowed to be placed inside an ActivityView:

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:allowEmbedded="true"
```

As you know, this is not documented, since ActivityView is not part of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Flutter and its [PlatformView](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/platform-views) API to display ActivityView as a widget. Unfortunately, both ActivityView and PlatformView are using virtual displays as the underlaying technology, and maybe it's not possible to show one virtual display inside another.