# How to access android.app.ActivityView in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an application where in I have to display different apps/activities. I decided to choose `ActivityView`. I went through some documentation [here](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/hmi/rotary_controller/app_developers#activityview) and some examples [here](https://medium.com/@dawidlijewski/activityview-advanced-way-of-composing-apps-6ca967e246ff) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635815/activityview-and-launching-activities-on-secondary-display) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522055/using-reflection-to-get-private-fields-from-a-hidden-aosp-class) and many more but I was not able to make anything to work. Google's documentation mentions a little about `ActivityView` but I was not able to find any examples.
I tried what is given in the examples/links that I've posted but nothing works.

My requirement is: I need to use `ActivityView` layout in one of my layout file and I need access to `ActivityView.StateCallback()` abstract class and `setCallback` method for me to carry on with my development. How do I access the `android.app.ActivityView` class?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @Javier ActivityView has been fully removed from Android 12 and above. I didn't go with this approach. If you'd like to have a look at how they had implemented launcher with ActivityView then you can look here: https://www.androidxref.cn/android-10.0.0_r47/xref/packages/apps/Car/Launcher/src/com/android/car/carlauncher/CarLauncher.java (on Android 10) and you can look here to figure out what they have used as a replacement for ActivityView here: https://www.androidxref.cn/android-12.0.0_r34/xref/packages/apps/Car/Launcher/src/com/android/car/carlauncher/CarLauncher.java (Android 12)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bijoy , I saw this repo before but it's any way to make Android studio recognize this classes? Since they are system api, Android studio doesn't recognize it and my app doesn't compile, do you know if there is any way to fix this?

Comment: Android has APIs which you can access from the SDK but there are certain APIs and classes which are hidden and is with the Android Platform. In our case it is ActivityView, to access it while developing an app we'll have to 1. clone the repo, 2. go to that specific package/class and make the method public (remove the @Hidden annotation from the methods/classes you want to be public) 3. build the package, you will get android.jar file, replace the android.jar file in the platform folder in android SDK location with the custom generated jar. You should be able to access ActivityView there.